# Vertical Alignment in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have 2 columns with 3 rows in a window. It looks like this:

[image]

How can I get rid of the extra vertical space after the QCheckBox in the first row of the first column?

this is my code:

```
QGridLayout *mainLayout = new QGridLayout;
QLabel *speedLabel = new QLabel(tr("speed (%)"));

mainLayout->setVerticalSpacing(5);
mainLayout->setColumnStretch(1,2);
mainLayout->addWidget(beginBool,0,0,Qt::AlignTop);
mainLayout->addWidget(speedLabel,1,0);
mainLayout->addWidget(speedSlider,2,0);
mainLayout->addWidget(graphic,0,1);

setLayout(mainLayout);
```

Comment: Do I get the wrong image? I do not see a QComboBox.

Comment: Woops, i meant QCheckBox

Comment: What is the `graphic` type?  I think it's the reason.

Comment: What's the size policy for the checkbox? I had similar issues with `QLabel`s before and changing the vertical size policy to `fixed` solved my problem.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, self-contained code sample that we can use to reproduce the issue.

Comment: The Graphic Type is a 400 x 400 QWidget.

How do I change size policy?

Comment: Using `beginBool->setSizePolicy( ..., ...)`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
mainLayout->addWidget(graphic,0,1);
```

to this:

```
 mainLayout->addWidget(graphic,0,1,3,1);
```

It will get rid of the extra vertical space.

(The cell of `graphic` will start at 0(row), 1(col) spanning 3 rows and 1 columns, see [QGridLayout::addWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#addWidget-2))